# PHPMyAdmin: No activity within 1800 seconds; please log in again error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have logged into phpmyadmin and have about 15 tables. I click on the one table and the data structure page loads up. I click on another and it works fine as well. However, when clicking on a certain table, it logs me out of phpmyadmin and I get this error message:

```
 No activity within 1800 seconds; please log in again
```

I logged back in again and every time I click the specific table, it's giving me the error message. No other tables are having this trouble.

Any reasons for the cause of this and how to fix.
Thanks

Comment: How is that table different from the others?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins 
What I did was took a copy of that error table by running the command create table tablename2 as select * from tablename1 and when viewing tablename2, no problems

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and cookies. Should work fine then.

Comment: change the value of  `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 86400;` in `config.inc.php`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also got the same Issue. I solved it by adding below line to my config.inc.php i.e by extending my time limit  from 1800 seconds to 86400 seconds

$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 86400;

For more details Please Refer the below link and follow the instructions over there.Thankyou!

http://firstcode.info/php-no-activity-within-1800-seconds-error/

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this happened to me when I clicked "reset" in the settings panel of PHPMyAdmin and then clicked "apply" while on the features tab, which basically set "Login cookie validity" to empty string.

Played around plenty with config files in `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/`, `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/`, and `/etc/phpmyadmin/` but no changes to login cookie validity had any effect.

So I figured PHPMyAdmin must have saved this dreaded configuration in a database. So I did the following:

`mysql -u root -p`

> Enter password:

`mysql> USE phpmyadmin`

> Database changed

`SHOW TABLES;`

```
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_phpmyadmin   |
+------------------------+
| pma__bookmark          |
| pma__central_columns   |
| pma__column_info       |
| pma__designer_settings |
| pma__export_templates  |
| pma__favorite          |
| pma__history           |
| pma__navigationhiding  |
| pma__pdf_pages         |
| pma__recent            |
| pma__relation          |
| pma__savedsearches     |
| pma__table_coords      |
| pma__table_info        |
| pma__table_uiprefs     |
| pma__tracking          |
| pma__userconfig        |
| pma__usergroups        |
| pma__users             |
+------------------------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`SELECT * FROM pma__userconfig`

```
+---------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| username      | timevalue           | config_data                                                                                                                                                                          |
+---------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root          | 2020-10-14 10:02:23 | {"LoginCookieValidity":"","LimitChars":500,"SQLQuery\/Explain":false,"SQLQuery\/ShowAsPHP":false,"MaxTableList":"","Server\/hide_db":"","collation_connection":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"} |
+---------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Sure enough, this is the bugger the config files weren't modifying. So I ran:

`DELETE FROM pma__userconfig WHERE username='root'`

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

`FLUSH TABLES pma__userconfig`

Then I restarted Apache for good measure:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

And voilà, all in the world was right again.